# Dynamically formatting text format/Masking in form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to write a form where users may enter a date and time (ie. 12/12/2005 3:45PM), and I'm attempting to mask the users input, such that the '/' and ':' dynamically appear as they type. I've found http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/, but is there a library which does something similar without the moving underscores? Preferably, I would like the user to be copy and paste already formatted dates into the form as well.

Comment: If you're using jquery, why not use the datepicker widget (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?  There is also a jquery.timepickr plugin for jquery (http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/).

Comment: Formatting user input as they type is extremely difficult to get right. It "works" for simple cases, but try cases where the user deletes characters, or uses backspace to insert new characters before removing previous ones, etc. Far better to wait for them to finish, then check formatting at the end.